# Split a row in a table into multiple rows from CSV

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I split a row into multiple rows with SQL?

I have a `.csv` file that I've imported into a table in MS Azure Data Studio, and SQL Server Management Studio (trying both). It is a table of invoices with a header ("H") and details ("D").

I need to split each row within the table into multiple rows at a specific delimiter or column number.

I have a table that looks like this:

[image: INPUT TABLE]

I need a table that looks like this, where each row is split at Column 8, and the data from the split row is inserted under the initial data.

[image: OUTPUT TABLE]

Here is how to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE InvoicesDemo2
(
    [Column1] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [Column2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Column3] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Column4] [date] NULL,
    [Column5] [date] NULL,
    [Column6] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [Column7] [money] NULL,
    [Column8] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Column9] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Column10] [money] NULL
)

INSERT INTO InvoicesDemo2 
VALUES ('H', 'VEN000002286', '27483387', '2023-02-14', '2023-02-14', NULL, 1840.60, 'D', '2501', 1840.60)
INSERT INTO InvoicesDemo2 
VALUES ('H', 'VEN000002286', '27480005', '2023-02-13', '2023-02-13', NULL, 243.39, 'D', '2501', 243.39)
INSERT INTO InvoicesDemo2 
VALUES ('H', 'VEN000002286', '27480003', '2023-02-13', '2023-02-13', NULL, 1601.64, 'D', '2501', 1601.64)
```

Thank you!

Comment: The row is not split evenly so I don't think I can use UNION ALL

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this. You are mixing header and detail rows. Your datatypes are all over the place. Storing numbers as strings. You have nothing from the two rows that tie them together. I would go back to your source data and try exporting this data in a normalized format.

Comment: Seems like there's more to this question than has been presented. How often do invoices have a set of `H` header values with only a single set of `D` detail values? That would seem to be the exception rather than the norm. What happens when there are multiple sets of `D` detail values? Are they added as another group of three columns to each line; is there another line in the CSV file repeating the `H` header values with the new `D` detail values; or something else?

Comment: Yes, I have to mix the header and detail rows because that's the format the database needs to print out a .csv for. 
Yes, I have to store numbers as stings because some of the rest of the data's invoice numbers have other characters besides numbers. This is just a small sample. Thanks.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning, there will only be a single set of D detail values. That is all that is required for the export of the .csv file.

Comment: But you have things like money stored as formatted strings. And your sample shows only a single detail row. Splitting this into rows as suggested would only create new issues because you can't reliably tie a given header to a given detail. If you have two detail rows with the same dollar amount your structure is broken. And you also have nothing you can use as a reliable ordering column in here. You probably need to generate two exports instead of munging all your data into a single row like this.

Comment: I would be pretty confident in saying there is a better solution. The database is for storing data, one should store it correctly. Let your application that needs to arrange it do the funny business.

Comment: The only real solution to unraveling this is using `UNION ALL`. But the real issue is that the whole approach here is just the wrong way to go about this.

Comment: Yes @SeanLange it is a dumb format, but I have to export the table to match a .csv exactly as this. There will only ever be one detail row. No need for multiple rows. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For getting match your desired format output you can try this query:

> Note: This query is based on your given data and expected output.

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6, Column7
FROM InvoicesDemo2
WHERE Column1 = 'H'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'D' as Column1,
       Column9 as Column2,
       Column10 as Column3,
       NULL as Column4,
       NULL as Column5,
       NULL as Column6,
       NULL as Column7
FROM InvoicesDemo2
WHERE Column1 = 'H'
ORDER BY Column2, Column1;
```

Comment: This is close @Nikunj ! I may have not given enough sample insert data for the table. Your answer does not stack the H and D rows one after the other. Instead it stacks all of the D rows then all of the H rows. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to union all, ordering by row number and row type e.g.

```
with cte as (
    select Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6, Column7
        , row_number () over (order by Column2, Column3) RowNumber, 
        , 0 RowOrder
    from MyTable

    union all
  
    select Column8, Column9, Column10, null, null, null, null
        , row_number () over (order by Column2, Column3) RowNumber 
        , 1 RowOrder
    from MyTable
)
select Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6, Column7
from cte
order by RowNumber asc, RowOrder asc;
```

Note: I am assuming that `order by Column2, Column3` gives the correct, unique, order of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

This is just dreadfully awful and something that really should not be done this way. I would really work hard to find a solution to fix the source data so isn't so absurd. But sometimes that just isn't possible.

Here is one way to deal with this. First I added a ROW_NUMBER so we can number each row from the original data. We need that in order for the final sort. This works with the sample data that you posted. I would be careful here as the datatypes seem to be a little suspect. And I would [avoid using the money datatype](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/avoid-use-money-smallmoney-datatypes) if at all possible.

```
with MergedData as
(
    select h.Column1
        , h.Column2
        , h.Column3
        , h.Column4
        , h.Column5
        , h.Column6
        , h.Column7
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by Column1)
    from InvoicesDemo2 h
    union all
    select d.Column8
        , d.Column9
        , d.Column10
        , null
        , null
        , null
        , null
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by Column1)
    from InvoicesDemo2 d
)
select md.Column1
    , md.Column2
    , md.Column3
    , md.Column4
    , md.Column5
    , md.Column6
    , md.Column7
from MergedData md
order by md.RowNum
    , md.Column1 desc
```

Answer (score -2):

So, you’re going to get a lot of questions.

The main one being - why would anybody want to do this like this?

I’m having a hard time thinking up a scenario where anyone would want to start with your input and end up with your output.

Your data types for column 3 and column 10 are mismatched, which may add another wrinkle for you.

But try this - edited to account for good ideas from Dale K.

```
WITH LiamsCte
As (

Select 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order By Column2) as MyRowNumber, 
Column1,
Column2,
Column3,
Column4,
Column5,
Column6,
Column7,
Column8,
Column9,
Column10
)

Select column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7
From LiamsCte
Order by MyRowNumber

Union All
Select column8, column9, column10, null, null, null, null
From LiamsCte

Order by MyRowNumber
```

It may throw you an error about data types in which case you need to google how to convert column3 (the one that is a money data type) to `nvarchar(50)`.

Comment: error : `Unknown column column1 in field list`

Comment: Your first select statement is missing the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Gavin, I have to have the table like this because I need to export the table to match a .csv file exactly. Your answer is the closest I've got but the rows aren't stacked one after the other.

Comment: @LiamGrist why not use a tool that is designed for this purpose? Even SSRS would make short work of your requirements.

Comment: Otherwise add a rownumber and table number to the unioned queries and then order by that.

Comment: I suggest `UNION ALL` also, since you know you don't have duplicates, `UNION ALL` typically runs much faster.

Comment: Stacked now, try that sweet edited code

Comment: Thanks @DaleK, I don't have SSRS but have looked into possible using Azure Data Factory's mapping features to create this .csv file. I think your idea about rownumber sounds good, its just over my head.

Comment: Are you serious to propose to google how to do a conversion within an answer? If you are not able to google that yourself and write in your answer, you should remove your answer. Keep in mind other people might have a similar issue as the OP and want to solve this. They would like to find an answer and that's what SO is done for. If they want to google, they use google instead of readings answers on SO.